# Magento 2 how to get sum of a column?

Tags: magento2, blocks, collection

I have created a custom collection factory. Now I want the sum of a column,how can I achieve it. Here is my code

```
$collection = $this->customFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('status',2)  ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',2)
->columns('SUM(total) AS total')
->group('customer_id');
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$collection = $this->customFactory->create()->addFieldToFilter('status',2)  ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',2);

$collection->getSelect()->columns(['total' => new \Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(total)')])->group('customer_id');;
```

Answer (score 7):

If it is a simple expression (as in this way) almost the same way as you add fields to select .... It is called expression field

`$collection = $this->customFactory->create()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status',2)
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id',2)
    ->addExpressionFieldToSelect('this_is_total', 'SUM({{total}})', 'total');`

and the group

`$collection
    ->getSelect()
        ->group('customer_id');`

if your expression is complex, use Rakesh's solution.